# Creation of an interactive "target" in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I am attaching an simple "wireframe" of an application i would like to create in Android Studio. It should be an application  able to count two shooters that are shooting two targets. Each shooter's score should be shown on a *score of shooter A* and a *score of shooter B*. I have created a similar application with help of an Udacity course, and i would like to enlightment my project with an actual interactable target, where if you tap the locations on the target, you get the score that is written to a *score of shooter A* and a *score of shooter B*. I know how to take value out of buttons, and also how to make the reset buttons work and also how to built a layout like this. What i don't know is how to create a target like this and to make it work and be interactable. Thank everyone for any advice.

**Wireframe:** [Wireframe img of my APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaNi2.png)

I have created an similar app like this with a help of really great Udacity course,

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Team A"
            android:textColor="#616161"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="56sp" />
        />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
            android:text="Free throw" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Team B"
            android:textColor="#616161"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="56sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
            android:text="+3 POINTS" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
            android:text="+2 POINTS" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
            android:text="FREE THROW" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:onClick="Reset"
    android:text="Reset" />
```

Java:

```
package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int ScoreOfTeamA = 0;
    int ScoreOfTeamB = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team A by 1 point.
     */
    public void addOneForTeamA(View v) {
        ScoreOfTeamA = ScoreOfTeamA + 1;
        displayForTeamA(ScoreOfTeamA);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team A by 2 points.
     */
    public void addTwoForTeamA(View v) {
        ScoreOfTeamA = ScoreOfTeamA + 2;
        displayForTeamA(ScoreOfTeamA);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team A by 3 points.
     */
    public void addThreeForTeamA(View v) {
        ScoreOfTeamA = ScoreOfTeamA + 3;
        displayForTeamA(ScoreOfTeamA);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 1 point.
     */
    public void addOneForTeamB(View v) {
        ScoreOfTeamB = ScoreOfTeamB + 1;
        displayForTeamB(ScoreOfTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 2 points.
     */
    public void addTwoForTeamB(View v) {
        ScoreOfTeamB = ScoreOfTeamB + 2;
        displayForTeamB(ScoreOfTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 3 points.
     */
    public void addThreeForTeamB(View v) {
        ScoreOfTeamB = ScoreOfTeamB + 3;
        displayForTeamB(ScoreOfTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team A.
     */
    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team B.
     */
    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    public void Reset(View v) {
        ScoreOfTeamA = 0;
        displayForTeamA(ScoreOfTeamA);
        ScoreOfTeamB = 0;
        displayForTeamB(ScoreOfTeamB);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to follow this. https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Thank you... Unfortunately, it goes way over my current abilities.

Comment: Well, that's what you asked for ;) Best of luck!